# filling a list from objects in another list

Tags: java, collections, nullpointerexception

iam trying to fill a list from type attendance with a list of students but i keep getting null pointer exception even though the students list is not empty but the attendance is empty ad the attendance has a property of student as following

Comment: At each `i` iteration, the `j` loop is same so you'll change each time the student value, and at the end all will have as student the last one

Comment: At which line is the `NullPointerException` occurring?

Comment: at this line  finalList.get(j).setstudent(temp); and when i debugged it temp is not null

Comment: i removed j and still i got the same issue

Comment: did you initialize the finalList? does it have j items so j-th item is not null?

Comment: also in second loop you iterate over the size of the listOfStudents list, I suppose you ment j < finalList.size() as mentioned in an answer below?

Comment: 1) See [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788/418556) & [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/218384/418556) 2) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: @kernelPain can you post structure for `listOfStudents` and `finalList`

Answer (score 0):

You have a correct loop but not in logic. Try this thank me later.

```
for (int i = 0; i < listOfStudents.size(); i++) {
    Learner temp = listOfStudents.get(i);
    for (int j = 0; j < finalList.size(); j++) {
        finalList.get(j).setstudent(temp);
    }
}
```

Comment: final list is empty so it will cause a null pointerException

Comment: well then if it is empty then Item on j-th position is null and it gives you a NullPointerException

Comment: i tried saving the length of listofstudents in a variable and used it as an iterator and it didnt work as well i still got null pointer exception

Comment: @kernelPain because it's not an issue with iterating over `listOfStudents`. It's an issue with `finalList.get(j).setstudent(temp)`, when you try to retrieve element from empty list, it will throw Exception.

Comment: i tried to set the student in an attendance object and instead of finalList.get(j) i tried finalList.add(object) still got the exception

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have `listOfStudents` of size 10 and `finalList` of size 5.

So when the first loop proceeds for the first time the `temp` is set to the first element of `listOfStudents`.

Now your seconds loop has to go from 0 to `listOfStudents.size()` which is equal to 10. So when it comes to `j = 5`, you want to execute `finalList.get(5).setstudent(temp);` but! the `finalList` only has 5 items, so when calling `get(5)` and above you get a NullPointerException because the size of the list is only 5.

Comment: when it gets to this loop a condition finalList.isEmpty  should be true

Comment: yes, but in the code you posted you don't check whether it is empty or not... so anyway, if it is of size 0, get(5) still returns a NullPointerException...

Comment: iwhen i tried to add the obk=ject to a list that is not empty it worked fine but when i tried to on a  new list it didnt work what am i messing here>